# How to intercept AD authentication attempts

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap

My work Windows account keeps locking and the unlocking process is frustrating *(you have to call the HelpDesk to request them account unlocking)*. They don't have any type of log and so they can't help me investigating the issue.

Is there a way to understand on my machine which software is trying to log into AD with the wrong password? (Possibly a method that does not require admin permissions)

Comment: This could be a denial-of-service attack. So IMO it's on-topic.